# How to find detailed error description in VS2008 from the project loading error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have an error when I try to open the project: 
The project file cannot be loaded.

Is there any place where I could find out where the problem might me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Output window . It usually shows the errors occured

```
Debug -> Windows -> Output
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the files and folders generated by IDE (.suo, bin, obj, etc) and then re-open your project. This has been the remedy for many cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the project is not available. (I can create the project, edit, save, but cannot open again ..) Isn't there really any place where a description is written? When I try to reload the project I get from IDE: The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error.

Comment: My last and fastest advice is to repair the MS Visual Studio.

Comment: Yep, I am now repairing the ide. Will let you know. Thanks

Comment: So, it think you have to re-install the IDE. that's the next step.